# Sharepoint: How to get value of the column?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have list in Sharepoint with new column "First line approvers".
Type of this column is "Person or Group" and "Allow multiple selections" is set to "Yes".

How can I get and modify values of this column in runtime(from workflow) ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've bound WorkflowProperties to the class..

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection f= new SPFieldUserValueCollection(WorkflowProperties.Web,WorkflowProperties.ListItem["First line approvers"] + "");
```

Then you can iterate over the collection / modify the collection and save your changes back by:

```
WorkflowProperties.ListItem["First line approvers"] = f.ToString(); //You might not need the to string here, I can't remember.
```

Comment: I try this methods but not working :|

from workflow:

    SPFieldUserValueCollection f= new SPFieldUserValueCollection(workflowProperties.Web, workflowProperties.List.Fields["First line approvers"] + "");

from page:

    SPFieldUserValueCollection f= new SPFieldUserValueCollection(Web, item.Fields["First line approvers"] + "");

Comment: ".ListItems" require Guid of the field or Index...

If I try to get value by index also I obtain empty SPFieldUserValueCollection.